# Error in adding an element to [String:Array<NSDictionary>] in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdictionary

I have a property in my `model` of Type : `[String:Array<NSDictionary>]`.
I want to add elements to this, in a loop. So this is what I do :

```
 for var k=0;k<body.count;k++ {
   var dict=body[k] as NSDictionary
   if(k==0) {
      self.model.data[i]!=[dict]
   }
   else {
      self.model.data[i]!.append(dict)
   }
}
```

When I do this, I get the following error :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The constructor initializes `model.data` to         `data=[String:Array<NSDictionary>]()`.

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i` was declared above in the code. It's of type `String`. That's not `nil`.I checked in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are unwrapping `self.model.data[i]` when you assign `[dict]` to it. I assume you are doing that in the case where `data[i]` has no value yet. So the forced unwrap will result in a nil pointer, which causes a crash.

Try this:

```
for var k=0;k<body.count;k++ {
   var dict=body[k] as NSDictionary
   if(k==0) {
      self.model.data[i]=[dict]
   }
   else {
      self.model.data[i]!.append(dict)
   }
}
```

Although this assumes that `self.model.data[i]` exists for the case where `k` is not equal to `0`. I am not sure if that is correct, you don't provide enough details.

What I *think* you are trying to do is this:

```
for var k = 0; k < body.count; k++ {
   var dict = body[k] as NSDictionary
   if self.model.data[i] == nil {
        self.model.data[i] = []
   }
   self.model.data[i]!.append(dict)
}
```